# Smack MUC invitation

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I there any way to listen for an incoming MultiUserChat using the regular packet filter.

Right now i have a class that handles all incoming packets and deals with them according to the type.

For example if the packet is an instance of message then the it is added into the database and a broadcast is sent.

This is how i am listening for incoming packets

```
public void registerListener(){
    Log.d("XMPP","New thread created for Message Listener");
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("XMPP","Message Listener Registered");
            PacketFilter filter = new AndFilter(new PacketTypeFilter(Message.class));
            PacketCollector collector = connection.createPacketCollector(filter);
            while (true) {
                Packet packet = collector.nextResult();
                packetManager.handlePacket(packet);
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smack already provides an API for that: [`MultiUserChat.addInvitationListener(InvitationListener)`](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html#addInvitationListener(org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection,%20org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.InvitationListener))

BTW: Is there a reason you use a PacketCollector instead of a PacketListener in your code? I would recommend using a PacketListener when it's possible.

Comment: Does this mean i would have to add an InvitationListener for each instance of MUC? because i have a class that manages multiple MUCs.

Comment: No, it's also not possible to add the listeners to instances, the method is static.

Comment: Thanks, the reason i used a PacketCollector is because i didn't know any better. Would you say it is better to use the PacketListener, if so why?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. PacketListeners are invoked in a Smack Thread, so if you perform long running computation there, it will block all following Listeners. For PacketCollectors you usually start a new thread, but it's important that you cleanup the PacketCollector when it's no longer needed or else you will leak resources.

Comment: Maybe that is why it keeps giving me a leaked intent. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, that's not the cause.